# Determine the expected rating for a product

Tags: probability, statistics

There are $N$ products, at each time point $t$ each product $i=1..N$ having $M_i$ 1-5 stars ratings.

1. Knowing values of $M_k$ for the product $k$ and the average rating for the entire set of products, determine the expected average rating for the product $k$ when $t\to\infty$.
2. Knowing all the $M_i$ for every product $i$, determine the expected average rating for the product $k$ when $t\to\infty$.

We assume an exponential distribution of $M_k$ dependently on time, that is $M_k$ increases linearly in average as $t$ grows, all time moments being equal.

The "philosophical" complexity is when a product $k$ has a very little number of ratings $M_k$, because if for example it has only one 5 stars rating, its expected rating may be below 5.

The problem 1 is theoretically more important but I suspect its calculations in practice may take too much CPU time, so I ask also 2.

This is a real problem, not a homework. Need to predict future ratings of products.

Comment: I don't understand - if the $M_k$" increase linearly as $t$ increases", then wouldn't the limit as $t\to\infty$ for $M_k$ just be $5$?

Comment: @Math1000 I need limit of the _average_ rating not of sum of the ratings. $M_i$ is the total number of ratings for a product $i$ each of which is $1..5$, we need the average number not this.